# How to obtain SpatialPolygonsDataframe that contains coordinates

Tags: r, gis

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of the Spanish census tracts and a set of coordinates.

What I would like to do is to obtain the subset of census tract that contains a pair of coordinates (as a new SpatialPolygonsDataFrame).

I came closest using 'over' following this example: https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/point-in-polygon But 'over' does not return a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. `seccion` contains columns "Long" and "Lat" with the coordinates. `map` is the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

```
# turn seccion into a SpatialPoints
coordinates(seccion) <- c("Long", "Lat")
# the coordinates are in the same lat/lon reference system (as is "map")
proj4string(seccion) <- proj4string(map)
# use 'over' with map as a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
# object, to determine which section (if any) contains the coordinates
sec <- over(seccion, map)
```

I tried other things and also had a look at the raster library but until now, no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `intersect` function from the `raster` package

Example data:

```
library(raster)
pols <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
pnts <- SpatialPoints(matrix(c(6, 5.91, 6.13, 6.23, 6.18, 
                       50.08, 49.95, 49.63, 49.64, 49.59),
                       ncol=2), proj4string=crs(pols))

x <- intersect(pols, pnts)
```

check out the result:

```
plot(pols, col='light gray')
plot(x, col='blue', add=TRUE)
points(pnts, pch=20, col='red')
```

It *is* possible to get there via `over` (note the order of the arguments)

```
v <- over(pols, pnts)
xx <- pols[which(!is.na(v)), ]
```